# Retrieving values from [object SVGCircleElement] in javascript using getAttribute

Tags: javascript, dom, svg

I have retrieved the value "[object SVGCircleElement]" in a javascript function and would like to unpack this so as to get more info on it, like its ID.
It is from a vanilla draggable function I have cribbed and don't think it is fully required here, the point is on the endDrag (mouseup) event I have a function which contains the variable [object SVGCircleElement]

```
function endDrag(evt){
alert(selectedElement);
selectedElement = false;
}
```

which gives me the `[object SVGCircleElement]`
How do I then get its ID, for example?
Thanks

Also - `[object SVGSVGElement]`. When the mouse is clicked on the draggable element, this object is passed to the function. The dragged element in the dom has values like ID and cy, cx and fill, which I would also like to retrieve.

Edit - 
Thanks to the answer below I was able to get info on the `[object SVGCircleElement]` by using the variable selectedElement and

```
selectedElement.id gets ID
selectedElement.getAttribute("cx")`enter code here` gets the cx (as this is a svg circle)
```

etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This string is just the stringification of the actual js object.

You could have seen it by using `console.log()` instead of `alert()`.

This object will expose a lot of properties and here is not the place to list them all. But for the `id`, well you can just access its `.id`  property.

However beware that for SVGElement, some properties are actually [SVGAnimatedStrings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGAnimatedString/) from which you need to access their `.baseVal`  property, or you may also just want to call [`Element.getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute).

```js
const selectedElement = document.querySelector('circle');

console.log('toString', selectedElement.toString());

console.log('.id', selectedElement.id);
console.log('.cx', selectedElement.cx); 
console.log('.getAttribute("cx")', selectedElement.getAttribute("cx"));
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <circle id="my-circle" cx="50" cy="50" r="50"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks, @Kaiido I am just looking in the console log now. One thing is that it breaks the selectedElement = false; statement at the end (adding it to the OP), which 'drops' the element

Comment: This statement doesn't drop the element no. The way variables are hoisted in js makes this statement useless. However, it may set the return value of your event handler to `false` and you can very well keep this by simply doing `return false`.

Comment: Thanks, will look at that. So I can actually get the id simply with 'selectedElement.id', and other values with 'getAttribute', that's great

Comment: I have got all I need without using the constant or the querySelector but will look into these so I can understand them properly. Cheers

Comment: By the way where would be the place to 'list them all' in reference to the object? What I mean is - is this DOM related or specifically javascript objects, and or is it specific to svg/xml for example. Help much appreciated so I can research it properly!

Comment: You can start by looking at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/circle from there, you'll find a few links to lower level classes from which this object inherits passing by SVGGraphicsElement or SVGElement, or even Element until Object. All these will bring some properties and methods to your final `selectedElement` instance.

Comment: Thanks again, for your time - I will check that out. (I had already been here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGCircleElement)